# How to add empty rows to the ExtJS Grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, rows

I have the grid with paging. Every page has max 10 rows. Like this:
[image]

I set gradient background for .x-grid3-scroller selector in CSS. Everything is fine, while there is 10 items in the DirectStore. But if there is less items than 10 I have that problem:
[image]

If set striped background for .x-grid3-scroller there will be no borders in columns.

How to add empty rows to the grid to fit grid to the bottom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After store is load (use `load` listener) check how many records are there (`getCount()` method) and add (`add()` method) `10 - store.getCount()` empty records.

```
store.on('load', function(store) {
  var records = new Array();
  for(var i = 10 - store.getCount(); i > 0; i--) {
     records.push(new store.recordType(/*you might need to provide default data here*/))
  }
  store.add(records);
});
```

Comment: thank you! I don't know why, but I thought that if I will add an empty records to the store this will break the pager. But everything is fine. Thank you again!